# Asp.Net MVC Authentication Cookie Conflict

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

Suppose I Created two **projects** with name  **ABC and XYZ** , and I am using **MVC's** Inbuilt Identity for **Security.** Then Problem is, If i login in app **ABC** I am also Logged In In XYZ . The Authentication Cookie created by **ABC** app is accepted by **XYZ**. How to resolve this **conflict.**

Comment: abc and xyz both are different projects with different url right ?

Comment: Yes absolutely , they are entirely different projects.

Comment: then they should create different cookies based on domain name and url. so there is not going to be conflict. are you facing any issue right now ?

Comment: As I am Using Inbuilt Identity to reduce my headache it automatically creates the cookie is there any way i can make some changes to the cookie ,so one is different from other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MVC5

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    CookieName = "Project1_ApplicationCookie",
    ...
}
```

MVC6

```
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options => {
    options.Cookie.Name = "Project1_ApplicationCookie";
    ...
});
```

Rename "Project1" to something relevant and change it between projects

Comment: Thnaks for your answer .